# getting "non_field_errors": [ "Unable to log in with provided credentials." ] on postman api login in django

Tags: django-rest-framework, postman, django-rest-knox

this is my models.py file :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from .manager import CustomUserManager

STATE_CHOICES = (
    ('Odisha', 'Odisha'),
    ('Karnataka', 'Karnataka')
)
ROLES = (
    ('admin', 'admin'),
    ('customer', 'customer'),
    ('seller', 'seller'),
)

class User_role(models.Model):
    role = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

class User_Profile(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    role = models.ForeignKey(User_role, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    selling_price = models.FloatField()
    discount_price = models.FloatField()
    description = models.TextField()
    productImg = models.ImageField(upload_to="productImages")

class Cart(models.Model):
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(User_Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

class Order_Placed(models.Model):
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(User_Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

this is my managers.py file :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None, role=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The Email field must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, username=username, role=role, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password=None, role=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        # Assign a default role for superusers
        if role is None:
            # role = 'admin'
            from .models import User_role
            role = User_role.objects.get(role='admin')

        return self.create_user(email, username, password, role, **extra_fields)
```

This is my serializers.py file :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers, validators
from .models import *
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password 

class RegisterSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User_Profile
        fields = ('username','email','password','role')

        extra_kwargs = {
            "password": {"write_only": True},
            "email": {
                "required": True,
                "validators": [
                    validators.UniqueValidator(
                        User_Profile.objects.all(), "A user with that email already exists" 
                    )
                ]
            }
        }
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        username = validated_data.get("username")
        email = validated_data.get("email")

        # Hashing the Password
        password = validated_data.get("password")
        # Hash the password using Django's password hasher
        hashed_password = make_password(password)
        # Update the validated_data with the hashed password
        validated_data['password'] = hashed_password
        password = hashed_password

        role = validated_data.get("role")

         # Check if the role is a string and convert it to an integer if needed
        if isinstance(role, str):
            role = int(role)

        user = User_Profile.objects.create(
            username= username,
            email= email,
            password= password,
            role = role
        )

        return user
```

This is my views.py file :

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.authtoken.serializers import AuthTokenSerializer
from knox.auth import AuthToken
from .serializers import RegisterSerializers

# user login API
@api_view(['POST']) 
def login_api(request):
    serializer = AuthTokenSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    user = serializer.validated_data['user']
    _, token = AuthToken.objects.create(user)
    return Response({
        'user_info': {
            'id': user.id,
            'username': user.username,
            'email': user.email
            },
        'token': token
    })

# get user data API
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_user_data(request):
    user = request.user

    if user.is_authenticated:
        return Response({
            'user_info': {
            'id': user.id,
            'username': user.username,
            'email': user.email
            },
    })

    return Response({'error':'not authenticated'},status=400)

# register user API
@api_view(['POST'])
def register_api(request):
    serializer = RegisterSerializers(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

    user = serializer.save()
    _, token = AuthToken.objects.create(user)

    return Response({
        'user_info': {
            'id': user.id,
            'username': user.username,
            'email': user.email
            },
        'token': token
        })
```

On postman app registration and logout is working fine but login is not working.

The passwords are stored in hashed format and also after registering tokens are saved in admin panel.

Please help me.